# Is there any way to search for phrase in multiple pdfs simultaneously

Tags: pdf, search, adobe-reader

Is there any way to search for phrase in multiple pdfs simultaneously? 
For example I have openned 4 pdfs and I look for phrase: "cat" in all of them at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of many possible would be to use [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=1436)

- it can search in all open .PDFs  or any selected folder
- can search for phrases or whole words

[image]

I assume you mean with "at the same time" that you want a one-click solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use Adobe Reader to [find text in multiple PDFs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c47.w.html):

> The Search window enables you to look for search terms in multiple
>   PDFs. For example, you can search across all PDFs in a specific
>   location or all files in an open PDF Portfolio.
>
> 1. Open Acrobat on your desktop (not in a web browser).
> 2. Do one of the following.
>
>    - In the Find toolbar, type the search text, and then choose Open Full Acrobat Search from the pop-up menu.
>    - In the Search window, type the search text.
>    - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
> 3. In the Search window, select All PDF Documents In. From the pop-up menu directly below this option, choose Browse For Location.
> 4. Select the location, either on your computer or on a network, and click OK.
> 5. To specify additional search criteria, click Show Advanced Options, and specify the options.
> 6. Click Search.
>
> Note: If documents are encrypted (have security applied to them), you
>   cannot search them as part of a multiple-document search. Open those
>   documents first and search them one at a time. However, documents
>   encrypted as Adobe Digital Editions are an exception and can be
>   searched as part of a multiple-document search.
>
> During a search, you can click a result or use keyboard shortcuts to
>   navigate the results without interrupting the search. Clicking the
>   Stop button under the search-progress bar cancels further searching
>   and limits the results to the occurrences already found. It doesn’t
>   close the Search window or delete the Results list. To see more
>   results, run a new search.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is nice to know that one don't have to install alternative pdf viewers. I've seen your profile on SU and there is one question that really interests me and you're probably the one with the knowledge. Could you please take a look? I think it is rare question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677541/are-there-any-heuristic-client-fetching-strategies-algorithms-theory-in-crm-weba

Comment: @Yoda Sorry, no idea :/

Comment: No problem : ). I thought that if you are expierienced in AI there might be something common. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with using the terminal for searching, [here's a small python script I wrote to do this](https://gist.github.com/teshanshanuka/260cea4e86d836d8e0c9a5a9e10d6807)

You'll need to install PyPDF2 package for this [`pip install PyPDF2`]

Usage:

```
python3 search.py a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf ... 'search_pattern'
```