# Full text search in multiple PDF documents on Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, search

Is there a tool for Windows that would enable me to search multiple PDF files (saved in one directory/subdirectories)? I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643438/2032064) at SO, but it gives answers only for Linux users. Are you aware of any solution for Windows?

I tried Total Commander plugins but none of them worked for me (either problems with 64bit version or just didn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to search for phrase in multiple pdfs simultaneously](http://superuser.com/questions/536153/is-there-any-way-to-search-for-phrase-in-multiple-pdfs-simultaneously), [Silly full text search?](http://superuser.com/questions/9628/silly-full-text-search) (silly question title) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Advanced PDF search features in Adobe.

To use the advanced PDF search option, you can choose Open Full Reader Search in the drop down menu of the search box or press SHIFT + CTRL + F.

It looks as if you did not take the time to do some research, [Googling for "search multiple PDF"](https://www.google.com/search?q=search+multiple+pdf) gives you the answer, e.g. [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-search-for-text-inside-multiple-pdf-files-at-once/).